# Python PyQt5 Type In Middle Of QLineEdit

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to change the settigns on a QLineInput So That When The User Starts Typing The Text Appears In The Centre Of The QLine Input rather than the left side.

Answer (score 0):

> Qt::AlignCenter - ( AlignVCenter | AlignHCenter ) Centers in both dimensions.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Widget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_edit = Qt.QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit.setAlignment(Qt.Qt.AlignCenter)           # <-----
        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def on_text_changed(self, text):
        width = self.line_edit.fontMetrics().width(text)
        self.line_edit.setMinimumWidth(width)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    mw = Widget()
    mw.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image]